# Variables aren't treated as local in WebStorm/PhpStorm rename refactoring

Tags: javascript, node.js, phpstorm, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

JavaScript variables that are considered local by JetBrains WebStorm/PhpStorm can be renamed in-place on Shift+F6:

[image]

Unfortunately, this happens only when a variable has local scope because of function scope.

The current project is ES6 Node.js, this means that *all newly defined variables are local*. But CommonJS module scope isn't taken into account, and block-scoped variables aren't considered local as well, IDE tries to rename them globally in entire project on Shift+F6:

[image]

This becomes frustrating. 'Looking for usages' is quite slow in a large project, and the risk of undesirable renames in other project files is too high, so multicursor edit and Ctrl+R search/replace are much more productive.

The project has `package.json` file in its root, `ECMAScript 6` in `Languages & Frameworks / JavaScript` and `ECMAScript 6`, `Node.js Core` in `Languages & Frameworks / JavaScript / Libraries` enabled.

How can this be treated? Is it a known bug?

Comment: Block-scoped vars and vars in CommonJS modules will be treated as local in the next WebStorm EAP. Though, WebStorm considers file to be CommonJS module if it has require or export assignment in this case.

Comment: @de1mar Are you referring to EAP in the last sentence, too? Because I've had module.exports and require in the file in 2016 and it wasn't any different.

Comment: Yep, I meant it had never worked as you wrote, but I've just fixed it and in the next WebStorm 2017.1 EAP the fix will be available.

Comment: @de1mar That's great news, thanks. You can submit the answer if you wish to, or I can submit it myself and give you credit for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to @de1mar, this have been fixed and will be available in WebStorm 2017.1 EAP.